# GKE Network policy and ExternalName

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I need to disable all egress traffic from my pod in namespace, except one direction, for example yahho.com
My service.yaml looks like:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: yahoo
 labels:
   output: allow
spec:
 type: ExternalName
 externalName: yahoo.com
```

And my network policy file blocks all output traffic:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all
  namespace: np-test
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

I've try to use the construction for allow:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-yahoo
  namespace: np-test
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: test-ubuntu
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          namespace: np-test 
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          output: allow
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
```

Can you correct my construction **podSelector** for passing traffic? I can't find any ideas in documentation.

Comment: Can you add the tank of the target pod and destination pod

Comment: But I don't need allow traffic between pods. I need to allow traffic from isolate pod to outside the kubernetes cluster. In my case it's specific resource in the Internet, which I can describe only via URL (for example yahoo.com).

Comment: Your current policy only allows traffic to go from pods labelled `name: test-ubuntu` going to pods with the label `output: allow` in the `np-test` namespace. It does not have a rule to allow any other egress.

Comment: You may want to add an egress ipBlock that allows traffic to the clusterIP of your service

Comment: Adding clusterIP didn't help

Comment: How is your pod making the request? Is it trying to resolve yahoo.com directly? Or is it trying yahoo.default.svc.cluster.local? Which IP does your request resolve to?

Comment: I've allowed DNS requests and resolve directly.

Comment: if you're sending requests directly to yahoo.com, the network policy will block it. Neither yahoo.com nor any of it's ip addresses are allowed

Comment: So, I have to use only this one construction:
`- ipBlock:`
But it doesn't flexible.

Comment: No you can use the others as well. But if you are directly resolving Yahoo.com in the normal fashion, then you need to allow your pod's egress traffic to go to the yahoo.com ip block. You might want to consider updating your code to call yahoo.com using `yahoo.default.svc.cluster.local` so that it resolves to the service cluster IP and the egress rule will allow the traffic through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately GKE does not support Network Policies with DNS-name-based egress filtering "out-of-the-box" due to Calico limitations: CIDR-based filtering is inflexible and error-prone, and does not work well for external resources. There is a [Feature Request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50453) on GitHub dated by 2017 for introducing support for a new parameter `DNSSelector` in Kubernetes API.

As for now, a third-party solution, the Cilium CNI plug-in provides DNS-based egress filtering. What is important, it supports wildcards.

Steps in brief:

1. Enable the GKE API for the current project, if not has been already done.
2. Build a standard 3-node GKE cluster without Network Policy support (with `kubenet`).
3. Connect to the freshly created Kubernetes cluster.
4. Create a cluster-admin-binding in GKE.
5. Create a custom namespace for your workloads, if necessary.
6. Create a headless service for the external resource, if necessary.
7. Run a Busybox container for checking the network policy effect.
8. Install Helm.
9. Use Helm to deploy Cilium.
10. Check availability of external resources before applying a network policy.
11. Create and deploy a Cilium network policy.
12. Check availability of external resources after applying a network policy.

As soon as you create the first network policy in a namespace, all other traffic is denied. There's no need in a headless service of type `ExternalName` but if you preferred to use it, restricted access via such service would work as well. `kube-dns` is in charge of name resolution. The network policy grants access to it.

Steps in details:

1. Enable the GKE API for the current project, if not enabled yet.

```
$ gcloud services enable --project "mylab" container.googleapis.com
```

2. Build a standard 3-node GKE cluster without Network Policy support (with `kubenet`). A parameter `--username` causes Basic authentication to be enabled.

```
$ gcloud container --project "mylab" clusters create "standard-cluster-1" --username "admin" --zone "europe-west3-c"
```

3. Connect to the freshly created Kubernetes cluster

```
$ gcloud auth list
$ gcloud auth login
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials standard-cluster-1 --zone europe-west3-c --project mylab
$ kubectl config get-clusters
$ kubectl cluster-info`
```

4. Create a cluster-admin-binding in GKE.

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole cluster-admin --user youraccount@google.com
```

5. Create a custom namespace `np-test` for your workloads and label it:

```
$ kubectl create namespace np-test
$ kubectl label namespace/np-test namespace=np-test
$ kubectl get namespace/np-test --show-labels`
```

6. Create a headless service for the external resource `example.com`, if you need.

```
$ vi example-service.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
  namespace: np-test
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: example.com

$ kubectl apply -f example-service.yaml
$ kubectl get services -n np-test
```

7. Run a Busybox container for checking the network policy effect.

```
$ vi busybox-pod.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox-pod
  namespace: np-test
  labels: 
    namespace: np-test
spec:
  containers:
  - image: radial/busyboxplus:curl
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox-container
  restartPolicy: Always

$ kubectl create -f ./busybox-pod.yaml
$ kubectl get pods -n np-test --show-labels
```

8. Install Helm on the CloudShell instance or a workstation you're working on:

```
$ curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3
$ chmod 700 get_helm.sh
$ ./get_helm.sh
$ helm version
```

9. Use Helm to deploy Cilium.

```
$ curl -LO https://github.com/cilium/cilium/archive/1.6.5.tar.gz
$ tar xzvf 1.6.5.tar.gz
$ cd cilium-1.6.5/install/kubernetes
```

Generate the required YAML files:

```
$ helm template cilium \
  --namespace cilium \
  --set global.nodeinit.enabled=true \
  --set nodeinit.reconfigureKubelet=true \
  --set nodeinit.removeCbrBridge=true \
  --set global.cni.binPath=/home/kubernetes/bin \
  > cilium.yaml
$ kubectl create namespace cilium
$ kubectl get namespaces
$ kubectl create -f cilium.yaml
```

Restart all pods in the `kube-system` namespace so they can be managed by Cilium:

```
$ kubectl delete pods -n kube-system $(kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,HOSTNETWORK:.spec.hostNetwork --no-headers=true | grep '<none>' | awk '{ print $1 }') 
$ kubectl -n cilium get pods
```

10. Check availability of external resources from within the Busybox pod **before** applying a network policy.

```
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- curl -kL google.com
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- curl -kL yahoo.com
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- curl -kL example.com
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- curl -kL -H 'host: example.com' example-service
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- nslookup example.com
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- nslookup example-service
```

Note that `example-service` is resolved into the same IP as `example.com`

11. Create and deploy a Cilium network policy. Now it's time to restrict access from the Pod to the Internet, and allow access to the `example.com` only.

```
$ vi dns-policy.yaml

apiVersion: "cilium.io/v2"
kind: CiliumNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: "dns-policy"
  namespace: np-test
spec:
  endpointSelector:
    matchLabels: 
      namespace: np-test
  egress:
  - toFQDNs:
    - matchName: "example.com"  
  - toEndpoints:
    - matchLabels:
        "k8s:io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": kube-system
        "k8s:k8s-app": kube-dns
    toPorts:
    - ports:
      - port: "53"
        protocol: ANY
      rules:
        dns:
        - matchPattern: "*"

$ kubectl create -f dns-policy.yaml
$ kubectl get CiliumNetworkPolicy -n np-test
```

12. Check the effect of the Network Policy. Check availability of external resources from within the Busybox pod **after** applying a network policy.

```
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- ping -c 3 google.com
100% packet loss
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- ping -c 3 yahoo.com
100% packet loss
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- ping -c 3 example-service
0% packet loss
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- ping -c 3 example.com
0% packet loss
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- curl -kL google.com
Connection timed out
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- curl -kL yahoo.com
Connection timed out
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- curl -kL example.com
OK
$ kubectl exec -n np-test busybox-pod -- curl -kL -H 'host: example.com' example-service
OK
```

As you can see the Cilium network policy allows access to the `example.com` directly or via a headless service whereas access to other sites is restricted.

This approach allows to obtain DNS-name-based egress filtering on GKE.

The links below provide more details regards described solution:

[GKE: Network overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview)

[Kubernetes Service: Headless Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)

[Kubernetes Service: Type ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)

[Kubernetes Service: DNS entry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns)

[GKE: Creating a cluster network policy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy)

[Kubernetes: Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)

[NetworkPolicy Egress with CIDRSelector and DNSSelector #50453](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50453)

[Kubernetes: Declare Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/)

[Open Source DNS-aware Kubernetes Network Policies Using Cilium](https://cilium.io/blog/2018/10/31/dns-kubernetes-network-policies/)

[Installation of Cilium on Google GKE](https://cilium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gettingstarted/k8s-install-gke/)

[Install Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#install-helm)

[Cilium: Locking down external access with DNS-based policies](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/gettingstarted/dns/#)